# How to make a sqli select query result display in an html table without defined columns

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to display the results of my select query on my webpage in a table, however the code im using at the moment uses a pre-defined set of columns. My code is this:

```
   $result= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Customers where First_name = '$specFirstName'");

echo "<table border=\"1px solid black\" width=\"80%\"><tr><th>Customer ID</th><th >First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>" ;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   echo "<tr><td style=\"text-align:center;\">". $row[('CustomerID')] . "</td><td style=\"text-align:center;\">".$row[('First_name')]."</td><td style=\"text-align:center;\">".$row[('Last_name')];
  echo "</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>"
```

Now, How can I do the same, but use the database headers in an automatically generated table? Can I also use this method to allow the user to specify the required columns in the query?
Many thanks,
Tommy

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` will gather the field names for you as it creates an associative array rather than numeric. Once you have that, `array_keys` will supply you with the column headers. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. You only have to define the `$columns` you want to display in the array map. This also works once you write the code to allow the user to select the columns she/he wants, you will only have to set this map with the selected options.

```
// Define the columns title and name in this array map.
$columns = array(
  'Customer ID' => 'CustomerID', 
  'First Name' => 'First_name',
  'Last Name' => 'Last_name'
);
// Run the query
$result= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE First_name = '$specFirstName'");

// Output table header
echo "<table border=\"1px solid black\" width=\"80%\"><tr>";
foreach ($column as $name => $col_name) {
  echo "<th>$name</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";

// Output rows 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($column as $name => $col_name) {
    echo "<td style=\"text-align:center;\">". $row[$col_name] . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
// Close table
echo "</table>"
```

Comment: Thanks! but I'm getting the following error at the following line Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/tommybu1/public_html/CottagesDatabase/View.php on line 42. The line is: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

Comment: I fixed it :-) I removed the $select and replaced it with * and it works fine now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the fields before the `while` loop like

```
$fields = ($result->fetch_fields());

?> <table border="1px solid black" width="80%"><tr> <?php
foreach($fields as $field) { 
    ?> <th><?php echo $field->name; ?></th> <?php
}
?> </tr> <?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  ?><tr><?php

  foreach($row as $val) {
        ?> <td style="text-align: center;"> <?php echo $val; ?> </td> <?php
  } 

  ?> </tr> <?php
}
?> </table> <?php
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is displaying all the feilds. And not retrieving the collumn names. any tips?

Comment: `column` and `field` are the same thing